# Collection of open subsets of a set X contains X

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm studying functional analysis on my own and I'm going through Kreyszig's text "Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications".

$X$ is an arbitrary metric space.

In section 1.3 he states 
"It's not difficult to show that the collection of all open subsets of X, call it $\mathcal{T}$, has the following properties:

(T1) $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}, X \in \mathcal{T}$

(T2) The union of any members of $\mathcal{T}$ is a member of $\mathcal{T}$.

(T3) The intersection of finitely many members of $\mathcal{T}$ is a member of $\mathcal{T}$."

I can't understand why it would be that $X \in \mathcal{T}$? Is this a typo? What if $X$ is a closed ball? Then it would seem $\mathcal{T}$ is an open ball and doesn't contain $X$.

Comment: If $X$ is closed (which it is in the $\mathcal{T}$ topology), it is clear that is an open set of his own space. The idea of an open set is a set on which you can take points near enough to any point which are contained in the set. If $X$ is your total set, it doesn't matter which point of $X$ you take as you can always take other points "near" which are still in $X$ (they can't be outside since $X$ is your total space).

Comment: $X$ is not a closed ball, it is the whole space. What do you mean by $\mathcal{T}$ is an open ball? $\mathcal{T}$ is the collection of all open subsets of $X$. And yes, $X$ itself is an open set.

Comment: The whole space is always closed since the complementary set is the empty set which is always open (a set is closed if the complementary one is open).

Comment: @Alfredo The whole space is always closed, but it is not necessary a closed ball. It's not the same thing.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure OP knows what is a general topological space. If he knew that he wouldn't have to ask this question. I guess he knows only the standard topology in metric spaces which is defined like this: $A$ is open if for each $a\in A$ there is $\epsilon>0$ such that the open ball around $a$ with radius $\epsilon$ is contained in $A$. With that definition it is clear that $X$ is open.

Comment: You are right. But what matters if $X$ is a closed ball or not? Don't you just get the space is bounded? But that doesn't affect the openess of $X$.

Comment: OP asked "What if $X$ is a closed ball?", that's why I mentioned it in my comment. I think he didn't understand what is $\mathcal{T}$ as he wrote "then $\mathcal{T}$ is an open ball and doesn't contain $X$". The important thing is that $\mathcal{T}$ is the collection of open subsets of $X$. And $X$ is open, hence $X\in\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm starting to understand now. I was thinking of X as being a set which could either be open or closed. But as you've all pointed out X is the whole metric space. In the text he even says "obviously, X is open" but I had not idea why this is obvious.

Comment: And yes, I was also confused about what $\mathcal{T}$ is. It is a collection of sets, not a single set.

Comment: Wait, so is an entire metric space X open or closed? It does contain a ball about each of its points, but its complement the null set is also open. Does this mean that X is both open and closed?

Comment: @Hunter Yes, $X$ is both open and closed. Same thing can be said about the empty set. In some metric spaces there are more such sets. (if there are more such sets we say the metric space is disconnected)

Answer (score 1):

The set $\mathcal T$ is the set of those subsets $A$ of $X$ such that$$(\forall a\in A)(\exists r>0):B_r(a)\subset A.$$Therefore, $X\in\mathcal T$; just take, for each $a\in X$, $r=1$. Then $B_r(a)\subset X$.

Answer (score 0):

Definition: A topological space is a pair $A=(X,T)$ where $T$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ that satisfies $(T1), (T2), (T3).$ The members of $T$ are called the open sets of $A.$ For any $Y\subset X$  the topological space $B=(Y,T')=(Y, \{t\cap Y: t\in T\})$ is called a subspace of $A.$

The open sets of $B$ are not necessarily open sets of $A.$

I think a fairly common misunderstanding of this is due to the very common practice of referring to the space $(X,T)$ as "the space $X$" and calling $(Y,T')$ "the subspace $Y$".

It is also common to say  "$Z$ is open in $X$" or "$Z$ is an open subset of $X$" instead of $Z\in T.$ And to say  "$W$ is open in $Y$"  for $W\in T'.$

A set is not intrinsically open or closed or neither.